# Copy/Paste, Delete option not working in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, copy-paste

I was trying to copy and paste some queries and noticed that the paste option is not working. After that I realized that my copy, paste, delete and next line option is not working at all. What will be the reason for this issue.

Comment: Hi Raghav, welcome to SO.  Have you tried quitting and restarting SSMS? Also, can you define 'Copy and paste some queries'?

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried doing it, its still the same

Comment: Do you only have issues with SSMS?  i.e. potentially a key could be stuck on your keyboard impacting all applications?  Also, are you running SSMS on your local machine or do you RDP onto another computer to use it?  Finally do you get this problem both when using keyboard shortcuts and when using the right-click action, or only with one?  Hopefully that will help narrow down possible options...

Comment: Sadly I've not had this problem so can't add much value, but this looks similar.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f5639985-7fb7-4240-89cc-cac006d13959/copypaste-fails-in-management-studio?forum=sqltools

Comment: Hi, I am only having the issue with SSMS

Answer (score 2):

When you press the Ctrl key, the text editor is looking for a mouse click to "Go to Definition".

Tools>Options>Text Editor>General> Uncheck "Enable mouse click to perform Go To Definition"
(or you can change the modifier key to something you use less often if you want to continue using this feature)

Answer (score 0):

just experienced the same situation in SSMS v18.5!
Also wasn't able to paste/copy code in the Query's Window.
After playing around and restarting the App it wouldn't work.
I did not have issues copying/pasting in all other applications.

Then I found a solution myself by simply thinking about how to "re-init" the engine of Copy/Paste in SSMS: 
**Go to:** Tools | Options | General | Check "Apply Cut or Copy to blank lines when there is no selection".

After applying the "fix" you should be able to copy/paste again! You may reset the checkmark later.

Hope you other guys have the same luck!

---

Edit: A few hours later the Copy/Paste again was not working and the fix did not work. I found out that a separate instance of Visual Studio had the same copy/paste problem. So it may be either a Windows 10 or .NET problem.
A reboot helped me in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too, and got a message saying my pc was out of memory. This could be caused by too many apps being open or too many background processes running.

Simply restarting the pc resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now on Windows 11 (previously using W10) and I'm using SSMS v19.1 and I have faced the same issue a couple of times on both Windows. When the issue occurs, it also happends in VS, even in Outlook, and thanks to the @Cordt answer, I decided to just close all .Net instances that I had open, then re-open them and bum the issue was gone, so no need to reboot your PC just the .NET instances to fix the problem.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score -1):

What, exactly, are you trying to copy, and from where? For instance, if you're attempting to copy and paste tables, views or stored procedures (etc) in the Object Explorer, you'll have no luck.

For most of these items, you should be able to right-click, select "Script [Table | View | Stored Procedure ] As > CREATE TO > New Query Editor Window", then run the script.

Unfortunately(?), SSMS isn't as easy going as Microsoft Access, there's definitely a little work involved.

Comment: Hi, I am just trying to copy a normal query from a note pad, also my delete and 'backspace' option and 'enter key' option is also not working

Comment: @raghavpillai - Could you put more detail into your original post, please, and maybe screen shots if you could.  Technically this is beyond the scope of this forum, however.